# Linq and SubSonic - returning nested complex types

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, subsonic, subsonic3

I'm new to SubSonic and reasonably new to LINQ as well, so I'm just trying to put a little app together.

I've got the templates all sorted and running okay, but I've run into a bit of trouble with this LINQ statement (simplified slightly, the real statement has some other joins but they don't affect this particular problem so I've removed them for brevity):

```
var addresses = from address in Database.Addresses.All()
                           select new Address()
                               {
                                   MyNestedType = new NestedType()
                                       {
                                           Field1 = address.ADDR1
                                       }
                               };
```

If I execute this statement I get the error *Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'NestedType'.* when I try to enumerate the results.

I'm probably overlooking the obvious but I can't see anywhere that I request such a conversion.

Both *Field1* and *address.ADDR1*  are strings.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

**Edit**:

I've had another look at this and in an effort to provide more information, I've created a small, complete example using SimpleRepository and an SQLite database that demonstrates the issue. Using SimpleRepository the error I get is different (Sequence contains no elements) but the result is the same. Here's the complete code:

```
 public class DatabaseAddress
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Address1 { get; set; }
 }

 public class Address
 {
     public NestedType MyNestedType;
 }

 public class NestedType
 {
     public string Field1 { get; set; }
 }

 static class Program
 {
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
         var repo = new SimpleRepository("Db", SimpleRepositoryOptions.RunMigrations);
         DatabaseAddress address1 = new DatabaseAddress();
         address1.Address1 = "Test";
         repo.Add(address1);
         var all = repo.All<DatabaseAddress>();
         var addresses = from address in repo.All<DatabaseAddress>()
                         select new Address { MyNestedType = new NestedType { Field1 = address.Address1 } };
    }
 }
```

In this example, `all` contains the object added to the database, but `addresses` returns "Sequence contains no elements".

If I use anonymous types instead of concrete types in the `select` statement it works.

There's obviously a gap in my knowledge here; any help appreciated.

Comment: There has to be something else wrong in your code, it's impossible to determine what is wrong based on the information provided.  Based off of this snippet, the only possibility is that Field1 is of type NestedType.  Since you say it's a string, then you haven't given us enough of your actual code to solve this.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I thought I'd added enough information as there really wasn't much more code than what I had posted. I've edited my original post and added a complete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call ToList(), otherwise the SubSonic provider tries to do something with MyNestedType and it doesn't exist in the database.

```
var addresses = from address in repo.All<DatabaseAddress>().ToList()
                        select new Address { MyNestedType = new NestedType { Field1 = address.Address1 } };
```

Update:  It also works if you call ToList afterwards, i.e.:

```
addresses.ToList().ForEach(address => Console.WriteLine("Address.MyNestedType.Field1 = {0}", address.MyNestedType.Field1));
```

I guess there is a bug in the SubSonic query provider, because it does work for anonymous types, as you mentioned.

Comment: That does it for me. I can now see where I was going wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Won't this defeat translation of where clauses and ordering, etc. to SQL because the entire table will be fetched and enumerated by calling ToList before any other translatable clauses are applied?

Comment: You can call ToList whenever it makes sense, just before the projection that is causing the issue:  i.e.:  var addresses = (from address in repo.All<DatabaseAddress>()
                             where address.Id < 4
                             orderby address.Address1
                             select address)
                             .ToList()
                             .Select(address => new Address { NestedType = new NestedType { Address1 = address.Address1 } });

Comment: Interesting, I guess I'll put this down to a Subsonic bug and restructure my code accordingly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Please see my question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111583/subsonic-3-linq-projection-issue-fixed-or-no).

Here's how you can test if it is the same issue:

In that sample code you posted, change Field1 in your NestedType to be named Address1.  Re-run your sample.  If it works, same issue and the fix I answered with in the linked question should solve it for you.

Comment: That doesn't seem to have fixed it in this case, but an interesting lead anyway which I'll look into, thanks.

Comment: This was almost right - MyNestedType also has to be renamed to match the class name, or vice-versa. Actually, I just tried it with Field1 unchanged, and it works, so just MyNestedType must be changed to match the class name (or the class renamed to MyNestedType).

Comment: Ah crap, nevermind, it didn't work, now I get the original error : Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'SubSonicTest.NestedType'.  I forgot to change it back from an anonymous type.  D'oh.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
var nestedTypes= from address in Database.Addresses.All()
                select new NestedType()
                {
                 Field1 = address.ADDR1
                };
```

Comment: That doesn't achieve what I'm after, which is one type nested inside another.