# Issue with Linq Join (subsonic)

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

I have this slice of code

```
IQueryable<Dealer> dealers =
    from dealer in Dealers
    join address in AddressesUS on dealer.DealerId equals address.OwnerId
    where dealer.Country == country && address.Owner == (int)Contact.OwnerType.Dealer
    select new Dealer()
    {
        DealerId = dealer.DealerId,
        DealerName = dealer.DealerName,
        Country = dealer.Country,
        Email = dealer.Email,
        Contact = dealer.Contact,
        Url = dealer.Url,
        IsActive = dealer.IsActive,
        IsWholesale = dealer.IsWholesale,
        Address = address == null ? null : address
    };
```

When I execute it (by calling ToArray or whatever), I get this error: System.InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to '***.Model.Address'

Now if I change the Dealer.Address to type string, the code fail to compile as I expected becaues it should really be of type AddressUS:Address.  However if I change the type of Dealer.Address to object and run the code, I see SubSonic populated it with first string column from DB.  I.E. dealer.Address = "123 Fake St."  There is no relation in DB for dealer and address so I am not sure if that would make a difference.

I am using .Net 3.5 and MySql 5.

Here is the stack trace

```
   at System.Convert.DefaultToType(IConvertible value, Type targetType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToType(Type type, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType)
   at SubSonic.Extensions.Objects.ChangeTypeTo(Object value, Type conversionType)
   at SubSonic.Extensions.Database.Load[T](IDataReader rdr, T item, List`1 ColumnNames)
   at SubSonic.Extensions.Database.ToEnumerable[T](IDataReader rdr, List`1 ColumnNames)
   at SubSonic.Linq.Structure.DbQueryProvider.Execute[T](QueryCommand`1 query, Object[] paramValues)
   at lambda_method(ExecutionScope )
   at SubSonic.Linq.Structure.DbQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
   at SubSonic.Linq.Structure.QueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
   at SubSonic.Linq.Structure.Query`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at InSite.Controllers.DealerController.GetDealers() in ***Controllers\DealerController.cs:line 25
   at lambda_method(ExecutionScope , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClassd.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__a()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
```

Comment: How is `address == null ? null : address` different from just `address`?

Comment: it's not, that's a left over code from when I try to do address = address == null ? null : new AddressUS {...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bug in Subsonic ... see this [Linq and SubSonic - returning nested complex types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255193/linq-and-subsonic-returning-nested-complex-types) for more information.

You can verify that it's the same problem by returning an anonymous type, instead of a Dealer, or by calling ToList() before the Select projection.  If it works in those cases, then it's the same bug.

Comment: Yeah, it definitely works when I use anonymous type.  I was pretty sure it was a bug, unfortunately I have deadlines otherwise I would've download the source code and see if I can fix it.

Comment: Can you log this as an issue or add some details if it's already logged on github http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0/issues