# LINQ GroupBy month

Tags: linq, subsonic, group-by

I am having trouble getting an IQueryable list of a (subsonic) object grouped by Month and Year.

Basic view of the object...

```
public partial class DatabaseObject
{
    [SubSonicPrimaryKey]
    public int objectID { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public decimal Value { get; set; }

    public string Category { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateOccurred { get; set; }
}
```

Method to get IQueryable in my Database repository...

```
public IQueryable GetData(string DataType)
{
   return (from t in db.All<DatabaseObject>()
           orderby t.DateOccurred descending
           select t)
          .Where(e => e.Category == DataType);  
}
```

My question is, how can I return the dates grouped by Month? I have tried the below, but this results in compiler warnings regarding anonymous types...

```
public IQueryable GetData(string DataType)
{
   var datalist = (from t in db.All<FinancialTransaction>().Where(e => e.Category == DataType);
                   let m = new
                   {
                       month = t.DateOccurred.Month,
                       year = t.DateOccurred.Year
                   }
                   group t by m into l select new
                   {
                       Description = string.Format("{0}/{1}", l.Key.month, l.Key.year),
                       Value = l.Sum(v => v.Value), // Sum(v => v.Value),
                       Category = "Grouped"
                       DateOccurred = l.Last(v => v.DateOccurred)
                   }
    return datalist;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this couple issues i found, but you basically need to select a Database object versus anonymous type?

```
IQueryable<DatabaseObject> datalist = (
from t in db.All<FinancialTransaction>().Where(e => e.Category == DataType)
let m = new
{
    month = t.DateOccurred.Month,
    year = t.DateOccurred.Year
}
group t by m into l 
select new DatabaseObject()
{
    Description = string.Format("{0}/{1}", l.Key.month, l.Key.year),
    Value = l.Sum(v => v.Value),   //Sum(v => v.Value),
    Category = "Grouped", 
    DateOccurred = l.Max(v => v.DateOccurred)
}).AsQueryable();
```

Let me know if my solution is now what you want.  I also noticed you were using Last?  The extension you were using I do not have so I replaced it with Max. I don't have subsonic installed so it might come with the libraries.

Comment: The only problem is that I seem to be doing something wrong when trying to manipulate the values, Description comes through as "01/01/1900 00:00:00" and Category as null. I even tried casting to a custom type of SimpleObject but the issue persists?

Comment: I just matched the logic you had and fixed your Anonymous type issue... my suggestion to you is to explain what you were trying to accomplish with the query you gave.  Either post it here, or as a new question.  There is probably a better way to accomplish what you need.

Comment: Nix, please see my answer below. The Anonymous type was a big help, the other part of the issue was due to Subsonic. I recommend LINQPad to anyone wishing to debug their LINQ queries.

Answer (score 1):

Any way don't combine LINQ in query syntax and LINQ in extension methods syntax. Use next:

```
from t in db.All<DatabaseObject>()    
where e.Category equals DataType
orderby t.DateOccurred descending
select t;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is apparantly to do with the way Subsonic interprests certain linq statements and is a [known bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535970/issue-with-linq-join-subsonic).

```
IEnumerable<DatabaseObject> datalist = (
from t in db.All<FinancialTransaction>().Where(e => e.Category == DataType).ToList()
let m = new
{
    month = t.DateOccurred.Month,
    year = t.DateOccurred.Year
}
group t by m into l 
select new DatabaseObject()
{
    Description = string.Format("{0}/{1}", l.Key.month, l.Key.year),
    Value = l.Sum(v => v.Value),   //Sum(v => v.Value),
    Category = "Grouped", 
    DateOccurred = l.Max(v => v.DateOccurred)
}).AsQueryable();
```

I have fixed this by declaring an list of type IEnumerable and using ToList() to cast the database interaction, finally the query is then recast AsQueryable()

Comment: Fun times...  did you try to put the ToList() at the end?  And removing the ASQueryable?

Comment: I want this to be Queryable as I am using some paging features that work well with this type.